# Is spring security OAuth valnurable to XSS? Why is the authorization request in the session?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

When we request an authorization from a Spring OAuth authorization server, [the server stores the authorization request that contains clientId and scopes in the session](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/27f16e57f5a15fc3a78b32aae0a33ac159d56df4/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/AuthorizationEndpoint.java#L177) if the user still needs to approve the request.

Next we are forwarded to the `confirm_access` page which displays some kind of form to the user where the user can approve or deny the request. After the user makes a decision, [the request from the session is continued to be used](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/27f16e57f5a15fc3a78b32aae0a33ac159d56df4/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/AuthorizationEndpoint.java#L202) and I don't see any check whether the authorization request in the session may have changed in the meantime. In case of the `DefaultUserApprovalHandler` the user will just [approve the request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2cd02fff04384dd311770a62e49ce4a20973cfff/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/approval/DefaultUserApprovalHandler.java#L68) whatever request there is, in case of the `ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler` [at least the scopes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2cd02fff04384dd311770a62e49ce4a20973cfff/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/approval/ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler.java#L198) are checked due to the nature of this approval handler, but not the client id.

So my concern is that while the user is staring at the approval screen and thinks about whether he should approve or deny the request the authorization request in the session changes and thus the user will approve unknowingly some random request. In best case this happens because the user opens another browser tab and starts a second request. In worst case an XSS attack happens during this time and an attacker thus gets a random approval instead of what the user actually wanted to approve.

Of course that is easy to fix, just a wrapper for the ApprovalHandler that requires scope and client_id as request parameters and matches them with the session which will get rid of the XSS problem and makes this just a small usability issue. But am I missing something what is built-in to prevent this behaviour? And why is the request stored in the session in the first place? Why not just pass the params on to the confirm_access view which in turn passes them back as URL params to approveOrDeny (which of course needs to be protected by a CSRF token).